# Why does this array not have to be returned?

Tags: c#

I am referring to the code on this site: http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
{
    var random = _random;
    for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
    {
        // Pick random element to swap.
        int j = random.Next(i); // 0 <= j <= i-1
        // Swap.
        T tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i - 1];
        array[i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Why does the array in `Shuffle<T>(T[] array)` not have to be returned? I thought in order to change the passed in value of a variable, and have it affect the variable in the method that called it, you would have to use `ref`. So why is there no `ref` being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301755.aspx

> Arrays are mechanisms that allow you to treat several items as a
>   single collection. The Microsoft® .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR)
>   supports single-dimensional arrays, multidimensional arrays, and
>   jagged arrays (arrays of arrays). All array types are implicitly
>   derived from System.Array, which itself is derived from System.Object.
>   This means that all arrays are always reference types which are
>   allocated on the managed heap, and your app's variable contains a
>   reference to the array and not the array itself.

Because they are reference types, the function in question is receiving a reference to the array.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `T[]` array is a reference type. The array itself is not being copied when `Shuffle` method is invoked - only the reference is, but it still points to the same array, so when you modify it's values within the method, you'll see it outside the method as well.